# NameError: name 'number' is not defined using css-selector as nth-child(n) with Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

```
click = self.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo > option:nth-child('+ index +').click()
```

Error:

```
click = self.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo > option:nth-child('+ index +')').click()
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

If i put in a non dynamic value inside nth-child(46) it works fine .

However id like to put nth-child(index)

Code trials:

```
basecss = '#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo > option'
events = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(basecss)


for index, val in enumerate(events, 1):
    name = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({})".format( basecss,index))

    print(index,val.text)

    if self.state == val.text:
        #event = self.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector(basecss + ("{}:nth-child({})").click())
        click = self.driver_web_browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Estadocombo > option:nth-child('+ index +')').click()
        print(type(click))
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a part of `enumerate`, **1** is passed as a integer and you need to convert it into string using `str()` as follows:

```
name = self.driver_web_browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("{}:nth-child({})".format( basecss, str(index)))
```